# Merge the tags menus and custom-menus

Tags: discussion, tags

While [custom-menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-menus) *should* be reserved for nav-menu questions most users just don’t get it: They use (and search probably in) just [menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menus). Retagging those questions has become an useless exercise, so I suggest to merge both tags to **menus**.

Opinions?

### Update

I merged `custom-menus` and `page-menus` with `menus` which is the canonical tag now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in chat I'm all for merging these tags. When people make menus they are always custom to them. So to me custom-menus and menus mean the same thing. Which one do you plan on making the primary tag?

Comment: I agree and think that `menus` should be primary

Comment: [tag:menus] should be the primary tag. I edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: +1. If users need help with core menu functions, they can always tag with e.g. `wp_list_pages` or `wp_page_menu`. **Note**: you may also want to make `wp_nav_menu` a *synonym* for `menus`. Maybe I should go try to do that...

Comment: @chip I am against synonyms for things that are names of specific functions. Nuances of making use of some (complex) function is not the same as generic question on larger topic.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider merging the [`page-menus` tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/page-menus/info). The [`page-menus`-tagged questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-menus) also appear to be primarily related to *custom menus*.